# Canvas и HorizontalScrollView

Tags: android, canvas, horizontalscrollview

Есть задача построить график, который бы скролился по оси Х. Для примера создал вот такой объект, который бы отрисовывал мне линию.

```
public class DrawView extends View {
    Paint paint = new Paint();

    public DrawView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawLine(100, 100, 300, 600, paint);
    }
}
```

Кладу его в разметку, которая лежит в HorizontalScrollView, результат - пусто, причем другие объекты типа Imageview кладутся нормально и скролятся без проблем.
Если же убрать HorizontalScrollView, то линия прекрасно отрисовывается. Может кто сталкивался с такой проблемой? Буду признателен любому совету

Разметка

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/leftLayout"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="29dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:gravity="right">

        <View
            android:layout_width="2dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/blue_dark" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/leftLayout">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/pointsLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/xLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>


        </RelativeLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Вот сам объект

```
public class GraphicField extends RelativeLayout {

    private LinearLayout xLayout;
    private RelativeLayout pointsLayout;

    public GraphicField(Context context) {
        super(context);

        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.graph_field, this);

        xLayout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.xLayout);
        pointsLayout = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.pointsLayout);

        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        DrawView drawView = new DrawView(getContext());
        drawView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        pointsLayout.addView(drawView);
    }
}
```

Comment: покажи разметку

Comment: @iamtihonov, добавил

Comment: для чего вы показываете объект GraphicField, который нигде не используется? И в разметке нет объекта DrawView, который должен рисовать линию.

Comment: Как это нигде не используется? DrawView  я кладу програмно в методе init() на pointsLayout. а сам GraphicField я отображаю в другом фрагменте.

Answer (score 1):

У вас xLayout занимает всю ширину, поэтому и не отображается View. Укажите ему android:layout_width="wrap_content"

Comment: xLayout, это разметка под ось X. Впринципе если я вообще уберу этот layout то ничего не изменится. Проблема именно с использованием Paint и canvas. Если же в pointsLayout положить другие любые вьюшки(например картинки) и указать им рандомные координаты, то все они прекрасно отобразятся, и будут скролится.

Comment: возможно вы не правильно добавляете DrawView. Покажите как вы это делаете, и сведите к минимуму код, показывайте только то что относится к вопросу. Например GraphicField, как я понимаю можно не показывать, вас будет легче тогда понять.